# What to do about near-duplicate answers from unregistered user(s)?

Tags: discussion, answers, specific-answer

[Is it feasible to have a literal ivory tower?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/106728/28789)

At 9:42 the unregistered user [bromey_jestman](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/48623/bromey-jestman) posted [this answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/106934/28789):

> A literal ivory tower would be one to two meter tall, simply the tusk of the elephant standing upright, in which a small enough fairy is living.
>
> Because: The literary ivory tower must, if I say so myself, stem from the German '''Elfenbein''' (ivory), where Elf seems to be a mix-up of "elf" (German ''Elb'' or ''Elf'', also ''Alp''or ''Alb'' as in ''Albtraum'' - ''nightmare'') and "eleph" as in "elephant", with a pinch of "alb" (''white'', as in ''albino'', ''alabaster''). While "Bein" (''leg'') is an archaic term for bone. Ivory tower then would be an ironic term, the irony of which is lost on most speakers in their ivory towers.
>
> On the other hand, "elephant" is thought to have came from afro-asiatic, through egyptian ''ꜣbw''; And "ivory" might have come from the egyptian root or from sanskrit ''इभ'' (''"íbha"'') and the term ivory tower might be a reference to size and power, obviously -- on yet another hand, ''ꜣbw'' was also used in hieroglyphs derived from ''ꜣb'' - "to stop, to avoid".
>
> By the way: I'd suspect "aleph", the ancient cow-god, is etymologically connected, more so because "Elephantenkuh" (fem. Elephant, Kuh=cow) and "Elephant Bull" are common terms. And because the elephant is holy in India.

At 9:44 the unregistered user [Irovy_Jestman](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/48624/irovy-jestman) posted [this answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/106935/28789):

> A literal ivory tower would be one to two meter tall, simply the tusk of the elephant standing upright, in which a small enough fairy is living.
>
> Because: The literary ivory tower must, if I say so myself, stem from the German '''Elfenbein''' (ivory), where Elf seems to be a mix-up of "elf" (German ''Elb'' or ''Elf'', also ''Alp''or ''Alb'' as in ''Albtraum'' - ''nightmare'') and "eleph" as in "elephant", with a pinch of "alb" (''white'', as in ''albino'', ''alabaster''). While "Bein" (''leg'') is an archaic term for bone. Ivory tower then would be an ironic term, the irony of which is lost on most speakers in their ivory towers.
>
> On the other hand, elephant came from afro-asiatic through egyptian ''ꜣbw'' ʾelbi).[1]
>
> By the way: I'd suspect "aleph", the ancient cow-god, is etymologically connected, more so because "Elephantenkuh" (fem. Elephant, Kuh=cow) and "Elephant Bull" are common terms.

As you can see both answers are nearly the same, except for the second one being a bit shorter in the third and fourth paragraph. The account names also show some similartiy. I left a comment under the second one to inform the OP about the option to have accounts merged, where to find the tour and help center and that *you shouldn't answer two times with basically the same answer - except for the second one being shorter*. That's what editing is for, which you can do when you create an account.

I then proceeded to flag the second answer as "Not an answer" so that it may get deleted - there is already a more elaborate answer that says the same in longer and to me at least it looks like a normal case of someone accidentally creating two accounts. My flag however was disputed and both answers still exist.

**Therefore I want to ask what to do in this case. I think the second answer should be deleted, but others seem to disagree. If we don't want to delete any of these two answers, what is the reasoning for leaving the same answer, likely written by the same user, *twice* under the question?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### If we're talking about this specific case only, I would say delete both.

The question asks about building a tower out of ivory. I think most of us would interpret that as asking about whether, if you had a large enough supply of ivory at your disposal, you could build a structure of any significant height. Therefore, a proper answer would . . .

- Hopefully talk about the material properties of ivory.
- Calculate, roughly, how much material would be needed.
- Make a basic estimate of the cost of such a tower.

These answers . . .

- Make something of a joke.
- Spend three paragraphs talking about etymology.
- Completely miss the three points I made above.

Therefore, in this case, I'd be inclined to delete both posts (and now they are, in fact, both deleted).

In a more general case - i.e. where one of the answers actually addressed the question - I think you'd be justified in editing in material from one answer to the other, to make it a full answer, and then flagging the incomplete one for deletion (or voting to delete, if possible). Additionally, [your comment](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/106728/is-it-feasible-to-have-a-literal-ivory-tower/106935#comment324323_106935) was rather nice:

> Welcome to WorldBuilding! Interesting analysis, but are you the same person that wrote [this answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/106934/28789)? Both accounts are unregistered. You might be interested in the question [How can one link / merge / combine / associate two accounts / users? (Anonymous / unregistered / cookie, or OpenID / registered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18232/352819) Merging allows you to [edit] your answers. Please don't post the same answer (shorter) again. If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more. Have fun!

Comment: Should the answers be deleted or just downvoted?

Comment: @James They're gone now.